# May one say G-d's name before washing netilat yadayim?

Tags: halacha, names, netilat-yadayim-washing, divine-names

May one say the word "G-d" or "Hashem" before washing his hands in the morning? For example, to say daily affirmations before getting out of bed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mishnah Berurah 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.1.8?lang=bi) writes that one may recite the "Modeh Ani" prayer before washing one's hands in the morning **because it does not contain any of G-d's Names, nor any *kinui* (idiomatic reference to G-d)**. The implication is that saying one of G-d's names or a *kinui* would not be permitted before washing hands in the morning.

Now, it seems that the English word "G-d" does indeed have the status of a *kinui* (see e.g. [R. Akiva Eger to Yoreh Deah 276:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbi_Akiva_Eiger_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.276.4?lang=bi)) and therefore should not be said before washing hands.

I would assume that the word "Hashem", which seems to have originally been formulated as a way of [referring to G-d's Name without using it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) (see e.g. [Yoma 3:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.3.8?lang=bi)) does not even have the status of a *kinui*, and could therefore be said before washing hands.

However, one could argue that nowadays the word "Hashem" has actually achieved the status of a *kinui* (in part thanks to its popularization in [ArtScroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArtScroll)'s prayer books). This is even more likely if your intent in saying this word is in fact to address G-d. If that is the case then it may indeed also be prohibited to say "Hashem" before washing hands.